# Using Hebrew on JSON code?

Tags: java, mysql, json, character-encoding, hebrew

I am using this code to POST and GET data from MySQL database .
However when getting data that is not in English, it is displayed as question marks ?
what changes do I make to enable Hebrew language use ?

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {

        if(method == "POST"){

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;

}
```

}

Comment: Never use `method == "POST"`, always use `method.equals("POST")` for String comparison.

Comment: `... new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1")` you're not using a unicode encoding here, but Latin-1, which doesn't support Hebrew characters.

Comment: You should consider using a more solid API than org.json's -- Jackson for instance

Comment: skiwi , thanks did what u said...

Comment: Thomas, so what should i use to support hebrew ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your HTTP response comes out encoded in Unicode (UTF-8 for example), and also your client (the application consuming the service) must be aware that of that encoding to read your response.

Comment: Well, JSON requires either UTF-8 or UTF-{16,32}. Not _all_ Unicode encodings are supported.

Comment: ... which means a library accepting a string as input and not a pure byte stream is kind of broken. The library should discover whether the byte stream contains UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32 big or little-endian and handle either.